# Java ImageIcon/Icon and JLabel is not working

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

Why is it that my code is not showing the image that I inserted? there's no compilation error or Syntax error  but why is it like that?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class FirstUI extends JFrame{

    private JLabel firstlabel;
    private JLabel secondLabel;
    private JLabel pie;
    public FirstUI(){
        super("Tittle");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        firstlabel = new JLabel("Hello World");
        firstlabel.setToolTipText("Hello World");

        String path = "pie.png";
        Icon pie = new ImageIcon(path);
        secondLabel = new JLabel("Text with icon",pie,SwingConstants.LEFT);
        add(secondLabel);
        add(firstlabel);
    }
}
```

main class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class FirstUiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

         FirstUI MyUI = new FirstUI();
         MyUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         MyUI.setSize(320,280);
         MyUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your image file with the class file or jar file? where you can run this file

Comment: The only issue I think may be with your code is the path to the icon.

Comment: @Pratik it's together with my Class file

Comment: check the system.getproperty("user.dir") method which helps you to get the right path. see [Java Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())

Comment: @user962206 : Had you sorted this question out, for finding the location of the images ? If not let me know, how you making this project, is it with simple notepad, or some IDE, like Eclipse. I might be able to show you some direction :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the "pie.png" is in the same Path of `FirstUI.class` try to use:

```
Icon pie = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( FirstUI.class.getResourceAsStream( "pie.png" ) ) );
```

Comment: The original code was invoking the constructor that presumes the `String` represents a `File`.  That would fail at time of deployment (once in a Jar).  Note that `new ImageIcon(FirstUI.class.getResource( "pie.png" ) );` will have much the same effect as what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this exact code, and it worked. It looks like pie.png cannot be found. If you're using eclipse, put it in the project root (The same folder that has /bin and /src). Otherwise, put it in the same directory where you run the java command from.

Comment: @user962206 Yep. I'd say that you're doing fine. Not knowing what you're doing, I don't know if you're getting there, but the code is all totally kosher.