# How to make a simple image class file in Java

Tags: java

Okai, so basically everything works but the second private class which I named project 2. In this program a grid of 2 by 2 is built out, now in one of the grid spaces (Project3), I want to have an image to be displayed.

```
  public class Project1 extends JFrame 
    {
        private Project2 topleft;           //  Buttons
        private Project3 topright;          //  Picture
        private Project4 bottomleft;        //  Schedule
        //private Project5 bottomright;     //  Help - Pad

    // Constructor

    public Project1() throws IOException
    {
        // Display a title.
        setTitle(" UAE University Interactive Course Calculator");

        // Specify an action for the close button.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create a GridLayout manager.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        // Create the custom panels.
        topleft = new Project2();
        topright = new Project3();
        bottomleft = new Project4();
        //bottomright = new Project5();


        //bottomright = new Project5();

        // Create the button panel.
        add(topleft);
        add(topright);
        add(bottomleft);
        //add(bottomright);

        // setting formatting options
        pack();
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        new Project1();
    }   
}
```

This is where I got to so far, maybe my logic is wrong. All I need is just an image to be displayed, that's all

```
public class Project3 extends JPanel 
{
    private JButton run,fancyButton, hel, but, done_by,exit, past;

    public Project3() 
    {
    Icon java1 = new ImageIcon( "untitled1.jpg" );
        fancyButton = new JButton( "Fancy Button", java1 );
    add(fancyButton);
    }
}
```

EDIT!!!: okai now this works, but it's a buttoned image, I want it to become just an image without the button any ideas?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You never add `fancyButton` to anything

Comment: I just want to know where I am wrong, and just want someone to tell me how to adjust my program in order for it to become a program with a simple image file

Comment: In `Project3` try adding `add(fancyButton);` under `fancyButton = new JButton( "Fancy Button", java1 );`. Also consider having a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: Refer this link [Java ImageIcon/Icon and JLabel is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168371/java-imageicon-icon-and-jlabel-is-not-working) . Most likely, its an issue with creating and loading of image icon.

Comment: In my existing Eclipse project, I put in your classes and created a "resources" folder and changed your one line to -  Icon java1 = new ImageIcon( "resources/untitled1.jpg" );  and its working. Instead of putting only image name, I put it with relative path and Icon gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest options to load and show an image on a JPanel:

1. Create an [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.net.URL)).
2. Create a [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20int)) and pass the ImageIcon as a parameter.
3. Add the JLabel to the JPanel (or any other swing component).

You can find a detailed example by reading [How to use icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).